# Ruby on Rails 3: Change default controller and parameter order in routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have a Rails app that has a controller called `domain` which has a nested controller called `subdomain` and `stats`. I have defined them in `routes.rb`:

```
resources :domains do
    resources :subdomains, :stats
end
```

I have changed the to_param of the domain and subdomain models to use the name of the domain, e.g.: the routing I get is `http://site/domains/foo/subdomains/bar`.

I would like to tidy it up to so that instead of using `http://site/domains/foo/subdomains/bar` I could access it with just `http://site/foo/subdomains/bar`. I have tried the following in `routes.rb`:

```
match "/:id/" => "domains#show", :as => :domain
```

Which works fine, but it only gives me the ability to use the path `http://site/foo` but for example `http://site/foo/subdomains/bar` doesn't. I could create match lines for every respective model and nested model but that does nothing to other helpers besides `domain_url` - i.e. edit_domain_url points to `/domains/foo/edit/` instead of `/foo/edit`.

Is there a way to change the routing so that the `resources` generates helpers that point to the root url without the 'domains' part?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The single `match` in your routes creates only one route. Resource helpers create many routes at once. Luckily there are a lot of options for customisation. If you want to omit `/domains/` from your paths, it's as simple as:

```
resources :domains, :path => "/" do
  resources :subdomains, :stats
end
```

With the above in `config/routes.rb`, running `rake routes` says the following:

```
    domain_subdomains GET    /:domain_id/subdomains(.:format)         
    domain_subdomains POST   /:domain_id/subdomains(.:format)         
 new_domain_subdomain GET    /:domain_id/subdomains/new(.:format)     
edit_domain_subdomain GET    /:domain_id/subdomains/:id/edit(.:format)
     domain_subdomain GET    /:domain_id/subdomains/:id(.:format)     
     domain_subdomain PUT    /:domain_id/subdomains/:id(.:format)     
     domain_subdomain DELETE /:domain_id/subdomains/:id(.:format)     
         domain_stats GET    /:domain_id/stats(.:format)              
         domain_stats POST   /:domain_id/stats(.:format)              
      new_domain_stat GET    /:domain_id/stats/new(.:format)          
     edit_domain_stat GET    /:domain_id/stats/:id/edit(.:format)     
          domain_stat GET    /:domain_id/stats/:id(.:format)          
          domain_stat PUT    /:domain_id/stats/:id(.:format)          
          domain_stat DELETE /:domain_id/stats/:id(.:format)          
              domains GET    /(.:format)                              
              domains POST   /(.:format)                              
           new_domain GET    /new(.:format)                           
          edit_domain GET    /:id/edit(.:format)                      
               domain GET    /:id(.:format)                           
               domain PUT    /:id(.:format)                           
               domain DELETE /:id(.:format)
```

Looks like all the routes you need!